# RangeError when init web3js

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, web3js

I am trying to use nuxt, vuex, and web3 and unfortunately I have a problem.

Indeed, when I call web3 in my store, I have an error telling me that "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

```js
import Web3 from "web3";
import {
    CONTRACT_BLOCKCHAIN_URL,
} from "../contracts/contract_info";

export const actions = {
    async initWeb3({ commit }) {
        try {
            const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || CONTRACT_BLOCKCHAIN_URL );
            await commit("INIT_WEB3", web3);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    },
};
```

However, if I call web3 directly in my component, I have no problem.
I also tried with my store on a Vuejs project and I have no problem.

Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You probably did a typo somewhere hence the infinite loop. You maybe have duplicate a name somewhere?

Comment: I just checked and there is no loop in my code

Comment: It's not that simple. Can you try to share some more relevant code?

Comment: I only have the code here, the only other code is my component where I call initWeb3

Comment: Btw, why do you `await commit`? A commit is sync. Only actions are async.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know then, thanks for the info, I remove.
I also just noticed that in my nuxt console, I had this error: ``Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs Web3``.

Comment: Try to google this one, it's a common issue. Either this one: https://www.reddit.com/r/Nuxt/comments/b5cjhc/nuxt_store_vuex_with_multiple_api_calls_using/  Or maybe this one: https://github.com/vuex-orm/vuex-orm/issues/255